# Retrieve column data into a struct

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

**End goal**: Read column values from DB, convert to strings, split and return the unique values.

I have a postgres table with 2 columns(both text datatype) that I am trying to read from such that key1 = column1_name, value1 = column1 values and key2 = column2_name, value2 = column2 values. Or get each col value in a separate variable altogether(key-value pair not needed then).

Table data looks like -

```
cities                countries
New York, LA          America
LA, Delhi, Mumbai     America, India
```

GORM has been used for ORM so I tried an approach -

```
Type Values struct {
   cities string
   countries string
}
var values []Values

db, err := gorm.Open(...)
result := db.Table("name").Select("cities, countries").Scan(&values)
// values[0] returns first row with col1, col2
// values[1] returns 2nd row "
// values looks like [{New York, LA, America}, {LA, Delhi, Mumbai, America, India}]
// I want - [{cities - New York, LA, Delhi, Mumbai}, {countries - America, India}]
```

// LA and America are repeated values which should either be removed at the time of querying or later
**I want the result to look like** -

**col1_name: col1 values =>
cities - New York, LA, Delhi, Mumbai**

**col2_name: col2 values =>
countries - America, India**

There are repeated values in the columns from which I need to return unique values for each column.

Please help me retrieve data in the required format to be ultimately returned as unique strings that can be passed into another function.

Comment: Can you make a [mre], with some data samples? It is, when looking at what you wrote, pretty hard to know what you have when you say "values in the DB are comma separated strings", in relation to the earlier code.

Comment: @Luuk done. Please check and let me know if more clarification should be added.

Comment: From a postgres point of view you want to do: `SELECT string_agg(city,',') as cities, string_agg(country,',') as countries FROM Table`, and not `SELECT city, country FROM Table`